# I want to combine multiple tables result count in one result using MySQl

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, logic

I want to combine multiple tables result count in one result with column wise using **MySql** (*see the result required*) but i am confuse about this if you have any query or optimize way regarding this please answer me or helps are definitely appreciated  also i was tried myself this **Query** with **Union** but seriously not success (*see the Query Example*)

Result required

```
post  post_comment_likes  post_comments  post_likes
2     0                   3              0
```

Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `post` FROM post WHERE user_id = "123456" UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `post_comment_likes` FROM post_comment_likes WHERE user_id = "123456" UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `post_comments` FROM post_comments WHERE user_id = "123456" UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `post_likes` FROM post_likes WHERE user_id = "123456"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @post = 0;
set @post_comment_likes = 0;
set @post_comments = 0;
Set @post_likes = 0;


 select count(*) into @post from .......;
 select count(*) into @post_comment_likes from ......;
 select count(*) into @post_comments from ......;
 select count(*) into @post_likes from ......;

select (@post + @post_comment_likes + @post_comments + @post_likes) ;
```

In the above code @post , @post_comment_likes , @post_comments , @post_likes are session variables , you prefix them with '@' character
Using the above code you have access to count of each table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM post 
         WHERE user_id = "123456") AS `post`
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM post_comment_likes
         WHERE user_id = "123456") AS `post_comment_likes`
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM post_comments
         WHERE user_id = "123456") AS `post_comments`
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM post_likes
         WHERE user_id = "123456") AS `post_likes`
```

You should replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(<some fieldname>)` and could use a variable for the user id.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the mysql query given below

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `post` FROM post WHERE user_id = "123456" ) AS post , 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `post_comment_likes` FROM post_comment_likes WHERE user_id ="123456") AS post_comment_likes,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `post_comments` FROM post_comments WHERE user_id = "123456") AS post_comments , 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `post_likes` FROM post_likes WHERE user_id = "123456" ) AS post_likes
```

thanks